# does it suffice to enable HAVE_RELIABLE_STACKTRACE option in config file and building the kernel to enable Live Kernel Patching ?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

the documentation for Live Kernel Patch uses the phrase "if the architecture has reliable stacks (HAVE_RELIABLE_STACKTRACE)." Does it mean that hardware also has a say in it or just enabling the config option HAVE_RELIABLE_STACKTRACE allows us to insert live kernel patch.

Also I am getting the fllowing error on inserting live patch :

```
livepatch: This architecture doesn't have support for the livepatch consistency model.
```

This is just because of HAVE_RELIABLE_STACKTRACE or is there something else I need to do ? 
I am doing all this on Ubuntu 14.04 X86 arch. I also have a BeagleBone black to play around with.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HAVE_RELIABLE_STACKTRACE` isn’t a selectable configuration option, it’s a configuration flag set by the build if the architecture and configuration support it. The only setup which enables this flag is 64-bit x86 with `UNWINDER_FRAME_POINTER` and `STACK_VALIDATION`.

This means that your BeagleBone Black can’t benefit from this option. It may be possible to develop the required features for it, but that hasn’t been done.

Comment: I didnt understand what you meant by "It may be possible to develop the required features for it", You mean to say that something can be done on the software side like in linux kernel or on the hardware side ?

Comment: I mean that something can be done in the kernel, assuming no specific hardware support is required.